# UWP crashes at InitializeComponent() [C++]

Tags: c++, visual-studio, xaml, uwp, initializecomponent

This is the weirdes error I've gotten so far while working on UWP. I was happily working when I ran my code to check some new changes. After the app executed the InitializeComponent() method it crashed. I went on the debugger mode and tried to narrow down what could be the cause of the problem.

The InitializeComponent() function looks like this:

```
    void ::SDKTemplate::Scenario3_DataBaseHandling::InitializeComponent(){
    if (_contentLoaded)
    {
        return;
    }
    _contentLoaded = true;
    ::Windows::Foundation::Uri^ resourceLocator = ref new ::Windows::Foundation::Uri(L"ms-appx:///Scenario3_DataBaseHandling.xaml");
    ::Windows::UI::Xaml::Application::LoadComponent(this, resourceLocator, ::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives::ComponentResourceLocation::Application);
}
```

After a few attempts I found that the error was coming after the last line was executed:

```
  ::Windows::UI::Xaml::Application::LoadComponent(this, resourceLocator, ::Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Primitives::ComponentResourceLocation::Application);
```

I am quite new to UWP programming so I don't understand what is the problem. From what I read on the documentation this line loads the components used on the XAML. But I don't understand why this problem is suddenly appearing now or its nature.

Could anyone give me directions to solve my problem?

Comment: Have you tried clean your solution and rebuild it ?

Comment: I tried your solution it didn't solve the problem right away but it gave me some new error messages that led me to the solution. Thank you @NicoZhu-MSFT

Comment: I found the same issue in [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f81a6999-0d4d-46ed-8d3d-49136a59a412/uwp-crashes-at-initializecomponent-c?forum=wpdevelop), And it has been replied. If you have solved your issue please fell free post your answer here and accepted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem came with my XAML code, I was trying to apply a "Style: TextBlockStyle" to a TextBox.